# How to hide folder routes on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance that hosts my site, and I have a question about it, well, I have folders inside the lamp's html folder, example folders are css, js, assets, and the problem is that whenever I type the domain of the site with the route of a folder or any other file, this is opened, example ec2-blah-blah-blah.com/assets (it shows everything inside the folder assets). The question is, how can I hide this? I don't want anyone to have access to folders or x files

Comment: Can someone help me?

Comment: Hey, can someone help? I really need help

Comment: StackOverflow is a site for Programming Q&A. It appears that your question is more related to the web server (Apache?) that you are using. You might find a better response by asking at: https://serverfault.com/ Also, your Question title does not seem related to what you are actually asking (it seems related to a web server rather than EC2).

Comment: Understand, thank you so much